# Which distribution in this case?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval, sampling

Let's say I am taking a sample size of n=1000 of a country population, and every one of them decides with '1' (for a specifc political party) or with '2' (for another political party).

Which distribution is given if I want to calculate the confidence interval for a proportional value pi?

Comment: Since you have a large random sample, you can assume it is normally distributed with mean $\hat{p}$. You'll need to estimate the standard error of this distribution to create a confidence interval.

Comment: @Kevin taking a large sample doesn't make the *sample* normally distributed. The distribution the sample was drawn from will be the same no matter what sample size you draw. It's the distribution of a (standardized) mean that might be argued to be approaching the normal.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: Agreed, I meant to say the sample proportion (instead of "it") - thanks!

Comment: If your question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Bernoulli distribution. This is a distribution that has only two values, which in this case you would designate 1 and 2, and  a single parameter, which dictates the probability of the outcome designated "success". Finding [a confidence interval for this parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) is a well-studied topic.